# How to run a link and a website script from Colab?

Tags: python, web, google-colaboratory

I generate a .json file in my Colab notebook that I need to upload to the following website: https://neuralmmo.github.io/client/
This will then run an in-browser simulation.

Is there a way to do this from Colab without instead of manually downloading the file, going to the website and uploading it myself?

I tried using kora library and expected to view the website in the notebook but I got an error.